# I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 64-bit ,It uses 8GB RAM

Tags: ubuntu, memory-management, ubuntu-12.04, ram, process-management

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 64-bit, My system configuration is **Memory**: 7.8 GB and **Processor** :Intel® Core™ i 7-2600 K CPU @ 3.40 GHz × 8 , in system monitor resource page it shows using **7.4 GB RAM** but overall process in process page uses around 3 GB RAM, how to find the which process using the  reaming RAM and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7.4 GB of memory is quite much. The system is probably allocating memory for buffers, and not all that memory is actually used.

You can inspect memory usage by running **top** and then pressing **M** (to sort processes for memory usage).

Comment: Htop is more fitted for this as top wont show the disk caching in the list but will show you that it is used in the top summary.

Comment: thanks guys, mysqld using 70% of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely not using all that ram, this is a very common misconception when using linux.
Linux is using memory that isn't being used for disk caching, if you start something that needs ram linux will stop to use it.

http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Also, this question is more fitted for [SU](https://superuser.com/) or [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) than stackoverflow.